# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", when the variable is defined?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xelement, object-reference

**EDIT: I found the error. I was setting the elements in the wrong place, and then calling their XPath in the right (different) place.**

---

I'm trying to get values of XML elements inside of another XElement, and when I try to get the value using `XPath`, it gives me the error in the title above. All of this is in the same class:

```
XElement x;

this.x =
    new XElement("parent",
        new XElement("child",
            new XElement("grand-child1",
                new XElement("great-grand-child1","Hello"),
                new XElement("great-grand-child2","World!")
            )
            new XElement("grand-child2","Testing123")
        )
    );

string get_str = this.x.XPathSelectElement("child/grand-child1/great-grand-child1").ToString();
```

It gives no errors during coding, but when I run it, it gives me the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", and it highlights the `string get_Str...` line.

Comment: I c/p'd this into a project on my machine and it works with no exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

Your `XPathSelectElement` is not selecting any element. It is returning null , hence the call to `ToString` results in the exception. Its not your object `x`.